# What would be the general form of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I come to a general form of this type of summation, similar to

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$
? 
I found this post about calculating higher powers of i, but am unsure if this would apply for negative powers as well: [Feyman's trick for Discrete calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182215/feymans-trick-for-discrete-calculus), as his formula: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^N n^{m+1} = \frac{N^{m+2}}{m+2}+N^{m+1}$$
results in dividing by 0 (zero) for m = -2. 
Also, How could I extrapolate for the more general form 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^k}$$ where k is some constant? This is my first StackExchange post, so feel free to give me tips on how to improve my posts. Thank you.

Edit: I have now learned that there is no rational closed form expression of the Harmonic numbers, But can someone explain why, or simplify another proof explaining why?

Comment: These are the so-called [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and no simple closed form is known.

Comment: **Note:** This sum does not converge!

Comment: And you are asking us to find $\zeta (1)$ except the limit is **not** $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you lulu. Should I close this question or leave it open?

Comment: @Mohammad Zuhair Khan: All the sums in Jonah's question (first version, in case later versions show up) are finite sums.

Comment: Why does convergence matter?  These are finite sums.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I know that but I just stated these facts so that he can verify his answers by using $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ for sums with $k > 1$.

Comment: @Randall I was just notifying him so that he does not treat it like a converging geometric series.

Comment: Oops my bad! I forgot that it does not have any common ratio or difference. My apologies.

Comment: "*should I close or leave open?*" Assuming the link to wikipedia that lulu provided fully answers your question, I would close it or answer it yourself, if you feel guilty about points then maybe as a community wiki.  As for how you might improve your posts in the future, this is a rather well formed question including some of your background knowledge like it should.  The only thing it suffers from is that it has a well known answer that a short phrase and a wikipedia link ought to be enough to satisfy all of your curiosity on the subject.  Keep asking questions and welcome to the site!

Comment: @JMoravitz well said. That piece of advice will also help me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you JMoravitz. I may leave it open in case of someone having an even better answer.

Comment: Jonah, if you want to read about the divergence behavior of this series (as $n \rightarrow \infty),$ see [my 1999 handout](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-1874348-6544585-537999/Euler-const.pdf) and Havil's book [**Gamma: Exploring Euler's Constant**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691141339). Incidentally, I wrote that handout several years before Havil's book came out -- at the time there wasn't anything easily available I could share with my students about how slowly the series diverged. I had thought of expanding it, but then Havil's book appeared (which I then cited).

Comment: So, upon expanding something I did last summer over the sum of a series of fractions with consecutive denominators, I think I came up with an expression that may work. $\frac {\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{N!}{i}}{N!} What is wrong with this? It works for k =1. I did this right now. I will open a second post inquiring about this.

Comment: The expression may work but it doesn't give you a closed form, you just rewrote the original series.

Comment: I realized that after posting.

Comment: Sorry to have to vote to close this as a dupe. Your extra question whether this sum can be written as a rational funcion of $n$ is [easy to handle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482118/11619). Take a look!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Thanks for sharing your thoughts (+1) - you did fine. Better luck next time not to hit a duplicate :-)