# Solving a cumulative recurrence relation

Tags: generating-functions, recursion

I am trying to obtain an explicit formula for $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $a_1=A>1$ and
$$(a_k)^{k^2}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}a_i, \; k=2, 3,...$$
What makes this recursive relation interesting, among other things, is the cumulative dependence of a given term on all terms of the sequence preceding that term.  From this recursive formula, after some iterative factoring, I found that
$$a_2=A^{\frac{1}{3}}, a_3=A^{(1+\frac{1}{3})\frac{1}{8}}, a_4=A^{(1+\frac{1}{3})(1+\frac{1}{8})\frac{1}{15}}, a_5=A^{(1+\frac{1}{3})(1+\frac{1}{8})(1+\frac{1}{15})\frac{1}{24}}.$$

So long as I did not make any computational error, I see the pattern is

$$a_k=A^{\frac{1}{k^2-1}\prod_{i=2}^{k-1}{1+\frac{1}{i^2-1}}}, \; k \ge 3 \qquad (1).$$

This formula is not in a particularly satisfying form; I would like to obtain a closed form expression of (1) without the product notation, and seek to prove that the resultant explicit formula corresponds to the recursive relation.  I would also be interested in other more direct, more elegant ways to obtain an explicit formula besides obtaining a closed form expression from (1).

Comment: The obvious suspicion is that your formula is as good as it gets. Most sums (and products) simply do not have closed forms. See this [discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52572/do-harmonic-numbers-have-a-closed-form-expression) and its references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my comment above, Maple gives a closed-form expression for your product in terms of the Gamma function.
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac1{i^2-1}\right)=
2\,{\frac {\Gamma  \left( k-\sqrt {2} \right) \Gamma  \left( k+\sqrt {
2} \right) }{\Gamma  \left( k-1 \right) \Gamma  \left( k+1 \right) 
\Gamma  \left( 2-\sqrt {2} \right) \Gamma  \left( 2+\sqrt {2} \right) 
}}.
$$