# General formula for $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} ... +\frac{1}{n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

We know that this series does not converge and tends to infinity but is there a general and exact formula for sum to n terms of this series

Comment: I don't think there's an exact formula. Probably an approximation

Comment: This seems related: [Do harmonic numbers have a “closed-form” expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52572) Maybe also some [other posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/52572) might be of interest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do harmonic numbers have a “closed-form” expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52572/do-harmonic-numbers-have-a-closed-form-expression)

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and is denoted $H_n$.

What do you think of this formula
$$H_n=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx?$$

Comment: Yeah you are right thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

As already answered by Lord Shark the Unknown, this is $H_n$.

For large values of $n$, there are good approximation using their asymptotics
$$H_n=\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ where $\gamma$ is Euler constant $(\approx 0.577216)$ which is very good even for small vales of $n$ as shown in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & H_n & H_n \approx & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 1 & 1.000000000 & 0.9938823316 \\
 2 & \frac{3}{2} & 1.500000000 & 1.499529512 \\
 3 & \frac{11}{6} & 1.833333333 & 1.833235361 \\
 4 & \frac{25}{12} & 2.083333333 & 2.083301693 \\
 5 & \frac{137}{60} & 2.283333333 & 2.283320244 \\
 6 & \frac{49}{20} & 2.450000000 & 2.449993653 \\
 7 & \frac{363}{140} & 2.592857143 & 2.592853705 \\
 8 & \frac{761}{280} & 2.717857143 & 2.717855123 \\
 9 & \frac{7129}{2520} & 2.828968254 & 2.828966991 \\
 10 & \frac{7381}{2520} & 2.928968254 & 2.928967425
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you claude