# Weird recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Find an explicit formula of the function E defined on natural numbers such that

$E(1) = 1$
and
$E(N) = 1 + \frac{E(1) + ... + E(N-1)}{N}$ for $N > 1$.

Comment: It looks like this recurrence defines exactly one function.

Comment: I rephrased the question slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N > 2$. Now,

$$
\begin{align}
E(N) & = 1 + \frac{E(1) + \dots + E(N-1)}{N} = \frac{\color{red}{[E(1) + \dots + E(N-2)]} + E(N-1)}{N} =\\
& = 1 + \frac{\color{red}{(N-1)(E(N-1)-1)} + E(N-1)}{N} = \color{blue}{1} + \frac{NE(N-1) - (N-1)}{N} = \\
& = \frac{NE(N-1) + \color{blue}{1}}{N} = E(N-1) + \frac{1}{N}.
\end{align}
$$

We also have that $E(2) = E(1) + \frac{1}{2}$ by a direct calculation, so we get

$$
E(N) = \sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j}.
$$

It is [likely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52572/do-harmonic-numbers-have-a-closed-form-expression) that we cannot do much better than this, without getting a more complicated expression (of course, that depends on what you intend to do with this).

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach 1:

- You might calculate the first few terms, then take first differences i.e. $E(n)-E(n-1)$, and then see if you can spot a pattern

Possible approach 2:

- $E(N) = 1 + \frac{E(1) + \cdots + E(N-1)}{N}$
- so $N E(N) = N + {E(1) + \cdots + E(N-1)}$
- so $(N+1) E(N) + 1 = (N+1) + {E(1) + \cdots + E(N-1)+E(N)}$
- so $E(N+1)  = 1 + \frac{E(1) + \cdots + E(N-1)+E(N)}{N+1} = E(N) + \frac{1}{N+1}$