# What is $\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, summation, closed-form

What is a closed form formula for the following?$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2}$$
I know that the summation
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
but is there a formula for the finite series? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do harmonic numbers have a “closed-form” expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52572/do-harmonic-numbers-have-a-closed-form-expression)

Comment: The finite sum is $\frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6} + \frac{1}{{n^2 }} - \zeta (2,n)$, where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function. You can obtain a number of different representations for your sum via known representations of the Hurwitz zeta function, see, e.g., https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11